# How to include C header from a separate Swift package into the C portion of another Swift package

Tags: swift

I'm writing a multi-platform game engine for fun in Swift. The basic layout of the Swift packages looks like this:

1. NativeTypes: Some C structs like Vectors, Matrices, whatever.
2. Engine: wraps some NativeTypes to make em usable, plus engine: basically everything but platform dependent code.
3. PlatformImplementation: contains a Swift target implementing the various platform specific protocols from Engine as well as a C target to implement the platform specific stuff like a Vulkan renderer and whatnot.

I  need to import the NativeTypes headers into the C portion of PlatformImplementation ideally, so I can  grab the types from there and feed them straight into my renderer. The alternative is to  duplicate the code (need to have the exact alignment, etc.) but of course that would be a pain.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out a (hackish, not ideal!) solution, for anyone who also has this problem. The trick is to just keep local dependency tree of all the packages and then just work around it in C. Implementation:

**1. Have the package that needs to import the C headers locally depend on the package containing the C headers. This way we can guarantee a stable folder structure:**

```
    dependencies:[
    .package(path: "./NativeCodePackage"),
    .package(path: "./OtherPackage")
],
```

**2. In your other package, import the headers you need from the first package by just navigating to them, like thus:**

```
    #define STR_IMPL(A) #A
#define STR(A) STR_IMPL(A)

#define NATIVEHEADERSDIR ../../../../../NativeCodePackage/Sources/NativeCodePackage/include
```

**3. Finally, just import:**

```
#include STR(NATIVEHEADERDIR/Maths/Vector.h)
```

If you would like to see a working implementation of this, check out my Swift engine project where I implement this solution:
https://github.com/forbiddencactus/Galah